# Converting One Data Type Object to another Data Type Object in WSO2 Config Lang

Tags: wso2, orchestration, wso2-esb

I am trying to convert one json payload to another, I have tried using `DataMapper` but the output payload does not match the input payload so I can't map both data.

I tried with enrich mediator but I can't seem to find my way through.

input json

```
{
    "requestID": "10001",
    "requestMode": "mode34",
    "channelCode": "34",
    "agentBusinessName": "34",
    "agentNumber": "34",
    "agentInstitutionCode": "001",
    "agentAccountNumber": "098788"
}
```

output json

```
{
    "BalanceEnquiryRequest": {

        "channel": null,
        "type": "mode34",
        "customerId": "098788",
        "customerIdType": null,
        "submissionTime": null,
        "reqTranId": "10001",
        "passcode": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just a single BalanceEnquiryRequest you can use the [PayloadFactory mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/PayloadFactory+Mediator).

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>
        {
            "BalanceEnquiryRequest": {
                "channel": null,
                "type": $1,
                "customerId": $2,
                ... etc
            }
        }
    </format>
    <args> 
        <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.requestMode"/>
        <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.agentAccountNumber"/>
        ... etc
    </args>
<payloadFactory>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to see the requirement whether there are single element or multiple.
If it's a single element then best option is to use payload mediator as suggested earlier.
If you want multiple elements then follow below steps.

Step 1 : Once the request comes in your sequence use the property mediator to convert it into XML

```
 <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING"
value="application/xml"/>
 <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
```

This would convert incoming json to XML.

Step 2 : Now use XSLT Mediator to convert into desired payload.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>    
    <xsl:template match="/">          
        {
        "BalanceEnquiryRequest": {        
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='root']">        
        "channel": null,
        "type": "<xsl:value-of select="requestMode"/>",
        "customerId": "<xsl:value-of select="agentAccountNumber"/>",
        "customerIdType": null,
        "submissionTime": null,
        "reqTranId": "<xsl:value-of select="requestID"/>",
        "passcode": null
        </xsl:for-each>
        }
        }        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```